# Android getExternalFilesDir permissions

Tags: android, permissions, android-4.4-kitkat

I know that for Android 4.4 you can create the "application specific" folder in external storage using this method.

```
getExternalFilesDir("myfiles").getAbsolutePath();
```

Which creates the folder 
    /storage/sdcard/Android/data/com.abc.zyz/files/myfiles

However is it safe to create it this way (my preferred) without the extra folder "files"?

```
String mfolder = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Android/data/" + getPackageName() + "/myfiles";
File sd = new File(mfolder);
if(!sd.exists() || !sd.isDirectory()) {
sd.mkdirs();
}
```

I've run it on API19 emulator and the folder is created using both methods, but I am concerned that when done on a real device that there could be a permissions issue doing it with the second preferred method.

Can anyone advise or test with a Kitkat device please?

Comment: I certainly would not rely upon this working over the long term. Also, never use string concatenation to create a path -- use the proper `File` constructor.

Answer (score 5):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
                 android:maxSdkVersion="18"/>
```

This will allow you to write to the external storage( i.e. save files) for for SDK earlier than 18 when it was required to give permission after that no permission is required. I know this question has been posted long back but thought the answer may help someone else cause it took me sometime to find this out

Comment: It should be **maxSdkVersion="21"** for Lollipop.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when reading this way. Works fine before 4.4, but on 4.4 it doesn't like it.

Add this to your AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Worked for me. Let me know if it does for you!

Comment: This is unlikely to be the problem, unless the (needed for years) WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission is also missing, because the docs say that any app that declares the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission is implicitly granted the read permission as well.

Comment: At the risk of adding a "me too", I have actually tested the above method on KitKat, and it does work (regardless of the permission setting). Going up another directory though, to above the "app" folder, it started failing. I found I had to stay inside the "app" folder (or subfolders) on both the SD card and internal, or I started getting "access denied" exceptions. On < KitKat there's no problem at all, but then you have to add that READ/WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in your manifest.